# iOS: Is it possible to stream audio from iOS client to server using HLS and if so, how? If not, how can I stream from iOS to a Red5 RTMP server?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, rtmp, http-live-streaming

On reading https://developer.apple.com/streaming/, what I understand is that HLS is used to stream audio or video from a server to an iOS device.

A) Is it possible to stream from the iOS client to the server using HLS? I want to capture audio from the device and do some processing on it on the server. I was told I could use HLS but it doesn't seem possible.

B) If it is not possible, anybody have any idea on streaming from iOS to a Red5 media server? I tried using the RTMP client library by midnight coders, but it keeps on giving "Connection reset by peer" issue very frequently which is annoying.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A) It is possible, yes. But I would not recommend it. HLS is a pull based protocol. Good for delivering to clients, but bad for ingesting. Would need to run a web server on the device, and packages the audio into a transport stream. And for the effort you would add unnecessary latency.

B) Would need WAY more information to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, szatmary!
Can you please advise the right way/best way to live stream audio from the iOS device to a server?

Comment: If we can't do it using HTTP Live streaming (HLS), what other protocol can I use? Also, is there any example you have seen of that? I believe Siri does it like that - so there must be a way.